# Light weight database for a Embedded Linux board

Tags: linux, embedded

Im actually working on a Embedded Linux board and I have got a requirement where I need to handle persistence of some relational data. So can anyone please suggest on various options available for the abovementioned.   Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a real programming question, now is it? In any case, I'd recommend sqlite3.

Comment: similar/duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023785/light-weight-sql-server-for-linux-windows

Comment: Well its not ..But thanks for your quick response ..Yes SQLite was one option Ive found but I was just checking if storing data into xml format would make it much faster to store and access.(The data I wanted to store is relational)

Comment: What is the characteristics of the data? Number of data types, size of records? What's the distribution between CRUD ops (is there any data which never deleted, just added)? How many space you have? What kind of storage you have? What's the frequency of operations, especially R/O vs R/W?

Comment: Im just curious if I could use XML format for storing relational data. Im also worried if the parsers would delay the process of storing and retrieving data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use C as programming language, try [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/). If you use Java, use [H2](http://www.h2database.com/).

But a database isn't always the best solution. So you should also consider something more simple, like a CSV or XML file, especially if the data rarely changes or when you only append.

Note that there is no generic answer to "what is the best option" since each case is slightly different. I suggest to build a small prototype to get a feeling what works and what doesn't. A technology might be great but if you can't wrap your mind around it, your code will be much more buggy than using an "inferior" technology which you can handle well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try sqlite3. it is small, tiny and lite perfectly suits for embedded environment. I have used it on ARM board for recording patient history. It is reliable and stable. Go for it.